# Why won't setSupportActionBar() recognize my toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting an error at the `setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);` for some reason.  It's suggesting me to create a method `setSupportActionBar()` that of which I did by clicking the red light bulb (it created it automatically).  The error is gone but when I then try to run my app, I still get an error on the simulator that says `MyApp has stopped working`.

Why's this happening?

```
private Toolbar mainToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some Title");
}

private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar mainToolbar) {}
```

Comment: which activity your are extending to?

Comment: @user3091574 I'm extending to AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import

`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

instead of

`android.widget.Toolbar`

Since you are extending `AppCompatActivity` which is in `android.support.v7` library, so you will have to import its library not others.